# Static method and constructor interception mocking in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mocking, powermock

All, Here is a problem that my searches have yielded little insight into. I think this should be a fairly common problem for all of us developing against big data frameworks but also seek 100% test coverage. So I will post the question here in an attempt to gather the best community response & ideas.

Consider the scenario where we need to mock a class that instantiate an external API object

```
class SolrClientWrapper {
   def doWork() = {
       val cli = new CloudSolrClient("zkHost1")
       ???
   }
}
```

To get 100% test coverage, and without actually relying on the Solr server to be up at all times during unit testing, we shall have a way to intercept the call to `new CloudSolrClient`. As far as I know, the ONLY library available is `PowerMock`

**Here is The Twist**
PowerMock and other Mock libraries require `asm` as a dependency, but a complex framework Spark project also require `asm`. There are version conflicts and thus (test-)runtime hell.

What is the best design refactor/libraries for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new `CloudSolrClient` object within the `SolrClientWrapper` class, it should be passed as a dependency. Then in your test you can pass a mock instead of the real object. Note that there are many dependency injection frameworks and mechanisms that can make it easier for you to manage your dependencies (e.g. to automatically instantiate them and pass to the constructor for you).

Not sure what `asm` is, but the code you posted should be easily testable without such dependencies once you remove parts of the code that instantiate stuff inside the class body (and thus the need to "intercept" anything).

Comment: I absolutely agree that dependency injection is the correct pattern to use. But how do you recommend that in the context of spark jobs? For example, traditionally spark jobs require the creation of a spark context and etc from main.

Comment: What's wrong with using actual context? You create the spark context in a "before" block and use it in your tests. This is ok because you don't need to intercept anything. See [this](http://mkuthan.github.io/blog/2015/03/01/spark-unit-testing/) or [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/09/making-apache-spark-testing-easy-with-spark-testing-base/). But for your `CloudSolrClient` you should use it as a dependency.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll have to explore these a bit further. It does lead to some rethinking about the architecture and dependency graph of framework concepts/ application logic and third party source/sink providers.

Comment: OK, glad it helped (at least a little)